# How to handle i18n for general web content, such as a privacy policy article?

Tags: java, internationalization, policy

To give you a view of the issue, http://www.google.com/intl/pl/policies/privacy/ is internationalized web content.

I know about resource bundles like in Spring and JSTL messages.  That type of text message resource seems a bad idea for whole web pages (too much text, hard to manage). Is there any standardized way, like messages or XML/HTML fragments with XSTL, for resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, other than the way google handled it?

- Distinct URL indicating "international": `*/intl`
- URL further qualified with a language code: `*/intl/pl`
- Various path contexts bridge from the language specific URL to the content: `*/intl/pl/policies`
- Language specific web page(s), handling the "too big texts" issue, qualified by the above URL.

Note that by placing the internationalization qualifiers first in this path, the set of translations for a given language are effectively "grouped together".  The converse might group by topic (policy/intl/pl) instead - that's an organizational decision to be made.

In considering what you might be reaching for in asking this question, it came to mind that perhaps you're looking to wrap such pages into a dynamic page presentation technology (JSP, JSF, struts, etc.).  Do keep in mind that both "dynamic web pages" and "static web page" content have purpose and do coexist in a web ecosystem: choose what's best, and find a way to bridge between the two.  In this case, think of the URL, to the static policy page, as the dynamic element your app could be controlling - and not the page content.

Comment: so this url is not resolved in some kind of servlet, but just by file dropped in folder?

Comment: Yes to "the file dropped in folder".  A servlet (or filter) *may* be involved in redirecting from a base URL (`/policies/privacy`) to a language specific URL (`/intl/pl/policies/privacy`).